# Prerequisites for Landau's Statistical Physics (volume 5)

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, education

I'm a mechanical engineer and I would like to study on my own Landau's Statistical Physics (volume 5). I've already studied thermodynamic and classical mechanic. For Landau's Statistical Physics are required knowledges in other physic fields?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is necessary to read volume III of quantum mechanics, it is like being in an arid desert, all the provisions are good to have, a little different style but with the time one starts to adore it.  :-)